# Grab the load average with top

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

The command below is grabing only the first load average, I would like to grab all the 3 load average. How can I change this code?

```
top -b -n 3 -d 1 | grep "load average" |  tail -n 1 | awk '/load average:/ {printf $10}'
```

Comment: "Have a look at `/proc/loadavg`" may be the easy answer. Isolate the 3 values with `awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }' /proc/loadavg`, `cut -d' ' -f-3 /proc/loadavg` or other unixish other text tools... or is it essential to get them from `top`?

Answer (score 5):

you should not use `grep | tail | awk`.

```
top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%s %s %s\n", $10, $11, $12 }'
```

have also a look at `w` or `uptime` or yetis's comment.

as suggested by cas,

number of field might not be the same, depending on OS.

```
uptime | awk -F' *,? *' '{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

Comment: nice really nice command! The output is something like this "0.10, 0.34, 0.39" would it be possible to output "0.10 0.34 0.39" without commas?

Comment: `top -b -n  1  | awk -F' *,? *' '/load average/ { printf "%s %s %s\n", $12, $13, $14 }'`.  but using an ncurses program like `top` for this is silly.  use `uptime` or `/proc/loadavg` instead.  `uptime  | awk -F' *,? *' '{print $11, $12, $13 }'`

Comment: @archemar - my version of top (procps-ng version 3.3.10 on debian sid) had loadavg in fields $12-$14 instead of $10-$12.