# How to make this awk command work

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to make the command below work but I can't. Please check this out:

```
echo "random string random string mark: abcde random string random string" |
    awk '{gensub(/^.*mark: (.{5,5}).*$/,"\\1","g"); print}'
```

I want this command to return only "abcde". 
But it is always returning the entire input string. Why?

Comment: The print command has no argument, so it prints the whole line.  Use something like "a=gensub(...)" and then "print a".

Comment: @Louis why not make that an answer?

Comment: @roaima  Well, I thought it was more like debugging or a syntax problem.  In fact, I expected the question to be put on hold as being off topic for that reason.  On the one hand, the fix was simple enough and I wanted to help.  On the other, I didn't want to look like I was chasing points by posting some trivial fix as an answer that doesn't really have anything to do with Unix/Linux.  The answers that are posted are much more useful than any fix I could come up with.  Are my cynicism and pessimism showing?  But thanks for your encouraging comment.  Next time I will try to post an answer.

Comment: @Louis, post an answer and include an explanation of why it works and/or why you've chosen to implement the solution in that particular way...perhaps also an explanation of why what the OP posted didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command gensub does not change the string. The result is an output of the function.

Please try:

```
echo "random string random string mark: abcde random string random string" |
awk '{print(gensub(/^.*mark: (.{5,5}).*$/,"\\1","g"))}'
```

---

#### Edit:

Turns out that the user needs parsing top output, which this does (as the user asks):

```
top -b -n 1 -d 1 |
awk 'NR==1{print(gensub(/.*load average: ([0-9\.\, ]+).*$/,"\\1","gs"))}'
```

Note: It is allowing both the dot and the comma for locales that use a comma as decimal separator.

Please take a look at mpstat [as presented here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html), it may be a better fit for your needs.

Comment: hi, acutally your code works perfectly! Really good but for reason I cant match multine with it. I actually need to use exactly your code (with awk and gensub) to get the load average of the "top" command. I know I can make it with many other ways, but I want to use regex and your really nice code. So far I have this code that does not work (even with your suggestion): top -b -n 1 -d 1 | awk '{print(gensub(/^.*load average: ([0-9\. ]*).*$/,"\\1","gs"))}'

Comment: worked exaclty as I wanted! Do you mind to tell me why does the NR solved the problem? And why cant I use "gensubs(.......);printf $0" ?

Comment: @Samul NR is the record number, so, only when the record number is 1 (the first line) is the command executed. The value of the $0 is **not** changed by gensub, so, if you print $0, you get an un-changed $0. You need to print the  "output" of gensub, and that is exactly what the command does.

Comment: You are awesome @binaryZebra! You are really awesome. Thank you so much. Do you mind helping me answer this last question related to this post? -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240136/gensub-on-multiple-lines

Comment: use `uptime` if you just want the load average.  parsing `top`'s output  is crazy.  this question was answered yesterday: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239952/grab-the-load-average-with-top

Comment: @cas Yes, parsing top's output is crazy, `uptime` is a much better fit for the need. I even wrote a recommendation to use something different in the answer. But the user is set in his ways.:-(..

Comment: yeah, my comment was meant for the OP to see. i forgot to write `@samul`.

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase your question: You want to print the first word after the string "mark: ".

On way, in awk:

```
echo "random string random string mark: abcde random string random string" | \
awk -v RS="mark: " 'NR==2{print $1}'
```

The above splits the string into two records separated by "mark: ", and then prints the first word of the second record (which is "abcde").

In sed:

```
echo "random string random string mark: abcde random string random string" | \
sed 's/.*mark: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

The above uses regular expressions to find the first non-space word after the "mark: ", and replaces the whole string with that word.

Comment: your code worked fine too! But how do I make it work if my "random string" has multilines on it? You code didnt work if I used multilines.

Comment: @Samul you didn't mention anywhere in your question that you needed this to work across multiple lines