# gensub on multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which has many random lines like

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee mark: 98 fff
ggg ggg jjjj iii
jjj kkkk
```

I want to use awk AND only gensub to match the number "98" above. So far I have this code below, I think it does not work cause I need to make gensub treat "\n" as any other character.

```
cat file.txt | awk 'printf(gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}'
```

I need the output of the code above to be only "98". How do I do that?

EDIT

even when I use the s or m modifier it does not work as it should cause as far as I know the "s" modifier should make regex treat . as any character including \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that `awk` treats its input as a multiline string. It doesn't. When you run an awk script on a file, the script is applied *to each line of the file* separately. So, your `gensub` was run once per line. You can actually do what you want with `awk` but it really isn't the best tool for the job.

As far as I can tell, you have a large file and only want to print a number that comes after `mark:` and whitespace. If so, all of these approaches are simpler than fooling around with `gensub`:

1. Use `grep` with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`)

   ```
   $ grep -oP 'mark:\s*\K\d+' file 
   98
   ```

   The `-o` makes `grep` only print the matching portion of the line. The `\K` is a PCRE construct which means "ignore anything matched before this point".
2. `sed`

   ```
   $ sed -n 's/.*mark:\s*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' file
   98
   ```

   The `-n` suppresses normal output. The `p` at the end makes `sed` print only if the substitution was successful. The regex itself captures a string of numbers following `mark:` and 0 or more whitespace characters and replaces the whole line with what was captured.
3. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -ne 'print if s/.*mark:\s*(\d+).*/$1/' file
   98
   ```

   The `-n` tells perl to read an input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e`. The script will print any lines where the substitution was successful.

If you really, really want to use `gensub`, you could do something like:

```
$ awk '/mark:/{print gensub(/.*mark:\s*([0-9]+).*/,"\\1","g")}' file
98
```

Personally, I would do it this way in awk:

```
$ awk '/mark:/{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"");print}' file
98
```

---

Since you seemed to be trying to get awk to receive multiline input, this is how you can do that (assuming there are no NULL characters in your file):

```
$ awk '{print(gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}' RS='\0' file
98
```

The `RS='\0'` sets the input record separator (that's what defines a "line" for `awk`) to `\0`. Since there are no such characters in your file, this results in `awk` reading the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest change to get it working will be:

```
cat file | awk '/mark:/{printf( "%s\n",gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}'
```

The /mark:/ is to select a line that contain "mark:".
But, then, why is a printf needed? This will also work:

```
cat file | awk '/mark:/{print(gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}'
```

But that would be a "[useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)", as awk could directly read from a file:

```
awk '/mark:/{print(gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}' file
```

---

#### Edit:

On user request: How to use the regex on file and string.

Well, with the rules you set: awk with only gensub is not possible.
Also, the idea of matching with `.*mark: ([0-9]+).*` to replace all of that with the match inside the parenthesis will mean that it is needed to match the whole file to extract a part. That is one reason why grep was created.

Just use:

```
grep -oP "mark: \K([0-9]+)" file
```

or:

```
echo "$string" | grep -oP "mark: \K([0-9]+)"
```

And you will get the result.

Comment: Really good, really good! But why is it so impossible to run a regex on a multiline string without those nice "workarounds" you gave me? Is it at least possible to remove the "\n\r" or "\n" from the string before using gensub? Something like "remove_linebreak(cat file.txt) | awk 'printf(gensub(/^.*mark: ([0-9]+).*$/,"\\1","g"))}'" ? Your answer is good but I really need to be able to run this on a file but also on a string so I would appreciate a lot if your answer could be using the pipe.

Comment: The regex is running on multiline, "one line at a time". So you need to select both row and column. Select the line, the use the regex.

Comment: @Samul because that's not a multiline string. Awk deals with single lines unless you tell it otherwise, so your script is run on each line separately.

Comment: @terdon so how do I tell "awk" to deal with multiple lines as if they where single lines?

Comment: @Samul see my answer. It is possible as I show in the end but there is usually a simpler approach.